# How to create an empty array within a TypeScript function, and add objects to it every time the function is called

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, es6-class

Using TypeScript and Angular, I am trying to create an empty array within my testConnection function that allows the addition of objects every time the function is called, without clearing the array.

testConnection function:

```
  testConnection(system) {
    var systemList = [];
    this.service.testConnection(system)
      .subscribe(conn => {
        if (conn == 'Success') {
          this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Found', 'success');
          system.isClicked = false;
          system.connection = true;
          systemList.push(system);
        }
        else {
          this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Failed', 'failure');
          system.isClicked = false;
          system.connection = false;
          systemList.push(system);
        }
      }, err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Currently, with the logic I have, it is adding the system object to the array, but since the empty array declaration is within the function, it is clearing and restarting this process every time the function is called. I have tried to declare the systemList at the top of the class (systemList = any[]), but when I try to reference it within the function, it is showing up as undefined.

How am I able to add system objects to the array any time the function is called, without clearing the existing objects out of the array?

Comment: If you need a state, that persists over multiple calls of a function, you have to define it outside of that function ... `systemList = any[]` is not a valid variable definition. Please show how you tried to define and use the systemList at class level

Comment: So, to paraphrase, this question should be "where do I store stateful information in Angular?". I don't know anything about that, but it's clear that your function is trying to do too much. Try to reduce the responsibilities of your function. Is it a function that maintains a stateful list? is it a function that sets up a service? or is it a function that subscribes to the "events" that the service kicks out and performs some action? Three substantially  different responsibilities but one function. Split things up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a component variable outside of the function, then the list will persist.

```
export class SystemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: TestConnectionService) {}

  systemList = []

  testConnection(system) {
    this.service.testConnection(system)
      .subscribe(conn => {
        this.systemList.push(system);
        if (conn === 'Success') {
          this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Found', 'success');
          system.isClicked = false;
          system.connection = true;
        }
        else {
          this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Failed', 'failure');
          system.isClicked = false;
          system.connection = false;
        }
      }, err => console.log(err));
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Another option is to create a service and use the service to hold the state of the system list which is more useful if you want multiple components to access the systemList.

```
interface System {
  some: string
  props: string
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SystemService {
  private _systemList$$ = new BehaviorSubject<System[]>([])


  get systemList(): System[] {
    return this._systemList$$.value
  }

  addToSystemList(system: System) {
    this._systemList$$.next([...this.systemList, system])
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

then your testConnection function would use it like this.

```
testConnection(system) {
  this.service.testConnection(system).subscribe(
    conn => {
      this.systemService.addToSystemList(system)
      if (conn === 'Success') {
        this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Found', 'success')
        system.isClicked = false
        system.connection = true
      } else {
        this.snackBarHandler.open('Connection Failed', 'failure')
        system.isClicked = false
        system.connection = false
      }
    },
    err => console.log(err)
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm not an Angular person but don't you need some more typescript types? `systemList: System[] = []`, `testConnection(system: System)`, etc.